# Android: Setting an activity as one of the fragments of a tab slider

Tags: android, tabs, fragment, viewer

I'm making an app where for each of the tabs I have, I want different things to occur. In this app, one tab would be for news articles, one tab for person lookup, and one for the wikipedia site (this is for a video game with api).

My question is this: Is it possible to set the content of one of the tabs to an activity I have already created? If so how and if not how should I accomplish my task.

Here is the code I have used to far. It is a sample from Android Studio.

```
public class MainActivity extends SampleActivityBase {

public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

// Whether the Log Fragment is currently shown
private boolean mLogShown;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        SlidingTabsBasicFragment fragment = new SlidingTabsBasicFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem logToggle = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_toggle_log);
    logToggle.setVisible(findViewById(R.id.sample_output) instanceof ViewAnimator);
    logToggle.setTitle(mLogShown ? R.string.sample_hide_log : R.string.sample_show_log);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_toggle_log:
            mLogShown = !mLogShown;
            ViewAnimator output = (ViewAnimator) findViewById(R.id.sample_output);
            if (mLogShown) {
                output.setDisplayedChild(1);
            } else {
                output.setDisplayedChild(0);
            }
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/** Create a chain of targets that will receive log data */
@Override
public void initializeLogging() {
    // Wraps Android's native log framework.
    LogWrapper logWrapper = new LogWrapper();
    // Using Log, front-end to the logging chain, emulates android.util.log method signatures.
    Log.setLogNode(logWrapper);

    // Filter strips out everything except the message text.
    MessageOnlyLogFilter msgFilter = new MessageOnlyLogFilter();
    logWrapper.setNext(msgFilter);

    // On screen logging via a fragment with a TextView.
    LogFragment logFragment = (LogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.log_fragment);
    msgFilter.setNext(logFragment.getLogView());

    Log.i(TAG, "Ready");
}
}
```

And here is the fragment:

```
public class SlidingTabsBasicFragment extends Fragment {

static final String LOG_TAG = "SlidingTabsBasicFragment";


private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;


private ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter());

    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);

}

class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return o == view;
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Item " + (position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,
                container, false);

        container.addView(view);

        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        title.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "instantiateItem() [position: " + position + "]");

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "destroyItem() [position: " + position + "]");
    }

}
}
```

If I was to use this code, how would I make a tab have the layout and the code of an activity.

Thanks for any and all help :)